# StateProgressBar for android studio

Tags: java, android

I already import in the dependencies the implementation `'com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar:stateprogressbar:1.0.0'`
and gives this error

> Class referenced in the layout file,
> com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar.StateProgressBar, was not found in the
> project or the libraries

```
<com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar.StateProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/your_state_progress_bar_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:spb_currentStateNumber="three"
        app:spb_maxStateNumber="four"
        app:spb_stateBackgroundColor="#BDBDBD"
        app:spb_stateForegroundColor="#009688"
        app:spb_stateNumberBackgroundColor="#808080"
        app:spb_stateNumberForegroundColor="#eeeeee"
        app:spb_currentStateDescriptionColor="#009688"
        app:spb_stateDescriptionColor="#808080"
        app:spb_animateToCurrentProgressState="true"
        app:spb_checkStateCompleted="true"/>
```

Comment: From gihub issue (https://github.com/kofigyan/StateProgressBar/issues/69) , it seems you need to `jcenter()` in your `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**You don't have to use a third-party library for it.**

Use this :

In XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_state1"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cv_green_circle" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_state1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Product ordered"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_progress1"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@color/grey" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_state2"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cv_grey_circle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_state2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Despetched"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_progress2"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@color/grey" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_state3"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cv_grey_circle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_state3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Out for delivery"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_progress3"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@color/grey" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_state4"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cv_grey_circle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_state4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Delivered"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>


// In activity :

 private void changeState(int status) {
   int stateId = 0, prgId = 0;
   for(int i = 1; i<=status; i++){

       stateId = getResources().getIdentifier("view_state"  + i, "id", getPackageName());
       View view = findViewById(stateId);
       view.setBackground(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cv_green_circle));

       if(i<status){
           prgId = getResources().getIdentifier("view_progress"  + i , "id", getPackageName());
           View prgView = findViewById(prgId);
           prgView.setBackgroundColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.purple_500));
       }
   }
}


// In cv_green_circle.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="@color/purple_500"/>

    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `jcenter()` to `settings.gradle` file in your project